# How can i click the element on webpage using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, e2e-testing

HTML information is :

```html
 <a title="Create an Account" class="button" href="http://demo.magentocommerce.com/customer/account/create/">
   <span>
     <span>Create an Account
     </span>
   </span>
</a>
```

Create an Account

I am trying with :

```
create_account_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title='Create an Account']")

create_account_button.click()
```

but it is not working

Comment: `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", create_account_button)`
this works sometimes when `.click()` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually assign the WebElement variable, u use the following code

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Create an Account']");
button.click();
```

Steps

1. Creating a `WebElement` variable button and assigning the value to it.
2. Performing `click()` on that webelement

***For Java follow above steps, for Python use below***

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title='Create an Account']').click()
```

Xpath you need To use be in `<a>` not in `<button>`

So try this Xpath `//a[@title='Create an Account']`

Comment: - I just went with below code                                                   create_account_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('button')

Comment: create_account_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@title='Create an Account']") -- both are working fine... Thanks deepak